# How to get the derivative of $\log_4 x$ using the change of base, but without assuming we have the derivative of $\ln x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I can compute the derivative of $\log_4 x$ using implicit differentiation.  I can also compute it by writing it as $\log_4 x = (\ln x)/(\ln 4)$ and using the fact that the derivative of $\ln x$ is $1/x$.  But I'm investigating why I can't seem to get it in the following approach, however bad an approach it might be.

Let $y = \log_4 x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln 4}$.  Now I raise $e$ to the equation, getting $$\exp(y) = \exp\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln 4}\right).$$  Using implicit differentiation, I get
\begin{align*}
\exp(y)y' &= \exp\left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln 4}\right) \left(\frac{\ln x}{\ln 4}\right)' = \exp\left(y\right) y'\\
\exp(y)y' - \exp(y)y' &= 0\\
(\exp(y) - \exp(y))y' &= 0
\end{align*}

In other words, it leads me nowhere.  Is it possible at all do this with the conditions imposed in the question?  It seems that if the exercise asks me to use a change of base, then I must really use the derivative of $\ln x$ to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't think this is possible , without differentiating ln(x) implies that you didn't define exp(x)because if you allow me to use the derivative of exp(x) the solution will have the proof of differentiating ln(x)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the derivative of $\exp(x)$ implies the derivative of $\ln x$?

Comment: They are inverse functions. They are defined based on each other. Let’s say you have $exp(ln(x))=x$ then taking the derivative you get $exp(ln(x))*ln(x)’=1=x*ln(x)’$ so $ln(x)’=1/x$

Comment: Interesting.  So it seems that if I have the derivative of a function, then I do have the derivative of its inverse as well.  Thank you, Malady and Ahmed.  The impositions of the question are, therefore, not sensible; not interesting.

Comment: Hint: write $x=e^{y\ln 4}$ so $1/y'=x\ln 4$.

Comment: Yep! A good rule of thumb is, when you’re analyzing something, *you need to use information about it* in order to arrive at any conclusion. In this case, the information you use is that $ln$ and $exp$ are inverses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $l=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\log_4(x+h)-\log_4(x)}{h}$
$$4^l=4^{(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\log_4(x+h)-\log_4(x)}{h})}$$
$$4^l=\lim_{h\to0}(\frac{x+h}{x})^{\frac{1}{h}}$$
$\lim_{h\to0}(\frac{x+h}{x})^{\frac{1}{h}}$ is the definition of $\exp(\frac{1}{x})$
so
$$4^l=\exp(\frac{1}{x})$$
$$l=\log_4({e^{\frac{1}{x}}})$$
then $l=\log_4({e}) \frac{1}{x}$

but this is the same way to proof that the derivative of $\ln(x)$ is$\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Thank you for this extra expression of the fact.